# Diagnalization of block matrix with circulant blocks

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, block-matrices, circulant-matrices

I have the following Matrix

$$A = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  X \\
  Y 
  \end{pmatrix}$$

Where X, and Y are circulant Matrices.
I want to diaganlize $AA^T$.

I tried the following:

$$AA^T = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  X \\
  Y 
  \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  X^T & Y^T 
  \end{pmatrix}
 =\begin{pmatrix}
  XX^T & XY^T\\
  YX^T & YY^T
  \end{pmatrix}$$

Now it is easy to show that $XY^T$ and obviously $YX^T$ are both circulant.
I end up with a general 2*2 block Matrix that is symmetric and block circulant as follows:
$G = \begin{pmatrix}
  X &  K\\
  K^T & Y
  \end{pmatrix}$ 
Now {X,K,Y} are all circulant. The question is how to diagnalize the final Matrix G efficiently.

My approach is as follows.
Since each circulant Matrix can be diagnalized using the columns of the DFT matrix (F) (i.e $X = FDF^H$) Where D is diagonal and X is circulant.

Then I can re-write G as follows:

$$G = \begin{pmatrix}
  F &  0\\
  0 & F
  \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  D_x &  D_k\\
  D_k & D_y
  \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  F^H &  0\\
  0 & F^H
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

I stopped at this point since I don't know how to efficiently diagonalize \begin{pmatrix}
  D_x &  D_k\\
  D_k & D_y
  \end{pmatrix}
using the the eignes of the blocks.

Maybe there is a more direct approach that can result into diagnalizing the block circulant matrix from the beginning. Note, in general my matrix is NOT BCCB(Block Circulant with Circulant Blocks) because X $\neq$ Y in general.